# JsTree json leaf detection

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a JsTree instance in which all childs are loaded async by a json call.

How can I detect if a user has **selected** a leaf node?

I've tried to use the success callback of ajax, but of course that also gets called if you simply open a Node with a "+". Is there an event like "child nodes loaded"?

Comment: You need to fire ajax to get the data. And then you can check if a node is a leaf type. Or am I missing something? Leaf or not leaf is data dependent. And you don't have data ready before ajax call finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radek, you are right.

In the end I've come up with another solution. While requesting the child nodes on the server I detect if a node has child nodes or not. By adding a Flag to the response dto it is possible to use this information on the client like this:

```
success: function (data) { 
  return $.map(data.d, function (item) {
    if(item.HasChildren)
      return {
          data: item.data,
          state: item.state,
          attr: item.attr,
          children: item.children
      };
      else
          return {
          data: item.data,
          attr: item.attr
      };
  })
}
```

If there are no 'children' and 'state' attributes in the response jsTree recognizes this as leaf node. Now you can use the .is_leaf(node) method of jsTree in the "node_select".